# Sign in with Apple Security for Linked Account

Tags: security, jwt, sign-in-with-apple

Assuming you have an existing user management/database on a web platform. Sign in with Apple should be integrated for a quicker login and registration process – although it will always create a regular account linked to an email address (just without a regular password). **Is it safe to use the (validated) JWT provided by Apple for authenticating?**

Signing in (existing account) would be the following steps:

- User taps on "Sign in with Apple" in an app
- the generated JWT from Apple is sent to the authentication server
- the server validates the JWT using the public keys provided by Apple's API endpoint
- the server extracts the email from the (validated) JWT and if a user with that email exists, this user is signed in (API returns internal access/refresh token for the session)

Comment: On your server, you must validate the signature of the JWS (id_token) and you should also validate the claims. The validation locally on the server cannot check however, whether the account has been disabled in the meantime. Since your server will receive the JWT shortly after authentication, I guess you can omit this check. Not sure what the Apple docs say and if you always should validate the JWT on their server, though.

Comment: Your forth bullet should be better rephrased to: "Sign-in User": the validated JWT will be used to check if an account (on your domain) exists. If no, create an account with the given UserInfo. Then create a domain specific access_token, refresh_token for aka "user session" and send it as response. Now the client can access your endpoints with the access token.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks for your replies! What do you mean with validate on their server? I renamed the fourth step, you are right – it is returning the access/refresh tokens of our system that the user uses during the session.

Comment: It requires more explanation. A server should not hand out an access_token when receiving _just_ a JWT. That happens on the token endpoint. And how this has to be done is specified in OIDC token endpoint ("authorization code", PKCE).

Comment: I took a look into Apple's REST API and was surprised that the token endpoint does not support PKCE when exchanging the authorization code. Which means basically, that apps are susceptible to authorization code interception attacks. In other words, your server cannot be 100% sure, it obtains the Apple access token (as a JWT) from _your_ app which is in turn supposed to obtain it from the token endpoint at Apple in a secure way. So, even when you validate the JWT, you can't be sure the receiver of your access token is who you think it is. I hope Apple will improve this, soon.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks! There is an "authorization code" that comes along with the JWT in an iOS app when the user signs in. The description of that is: "A short-lived, one-time valid token that can provides proof of authorization to the server component of your app. The authorization code is bound to the specific transaction using the state attribute passed in the authorization request. The server component of your app can validate the code using the Apple identity service endpoint." – for some reason I can't find that identity service endpoint in the apple documentation...

Comment: You use the authorization code on the token endpoint (Apple's) to get an access token. According the docs, you have to pass a client_secret along other parameters in your request. (Usually, non-confidential clients (SPA, mobile) should use PKCE instead a secret to enhance security.) Anyway, the access token you get from the token endpoint can be send to your server, which MUST be validated there, and then your server _can_ send your client your domain access token.

Comment: Due to the "chain of trust", a server receiving an access token "trusts" the sender. All checks have been done before to ensure that the sender is authenticated and has the right to posses the access token. The authorization code in contrast is not sufficient (that's the reason to have PKCE which ensures a secure exchange of the auth-code with an access-token on the token endpoint).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks again! When sending this authorization code to the token endpoint at apple, it returns a refresh and access token – in my use case (where a user has his own regular account), these tokens can be discarded? So in the steps in my question above a new step between 3 and 4 would be added:
* send authorization code to apples token endpoint and make sure it succeeds
Or is there anything else I would need to do with that refresh/access token?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood this. This is what I found: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120695?answerId=374764022#374764022 – looks like the token endpoint is only for web apps using sign in with apple. It also always requires a redirect_uri to be set (which doesn't make sense in the app). According to this it seems to be sufficient to just validate the JWT when using an iOS App

Comment: It was not clear whether you build an iOS app or web app. When you have an iOS app, you should use Apple's Authentication framework. What they exactly do internally is not documented. Generally, when a client receives the auth response containing user, id_token, code and state, it must validate it (either Apples framework or your app) (see OIDC). A native app would now exchange the code for an access token. Your server should only  trust the access token - not `code`. So, I have my questions here myself. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to craft an answer for iOS apps. But first clarify the question:

"Is it safe to use the (validated) JWT provided by Apple for authenticating?"

The only known JWT we receive from an Authorization task is the "id_token". Other parameters may be JWTs as well, but these are opaque for the client.

The question is now, if we send the id_token to the app server, is it sufficient to just validate the id_token to hand out the client an access token for the app server's domain? Answer: NO!

When using Apple's Authentication Framework for iOS for Sign in With Apple, the Authorization task returns an `ASAuthorization` value in the completion handler. This contains basically the following parameters:

- `user`: an identifier
- `identityToken`: JWT  the "id_token" (see OIDC)
- `authorizationCode`: A short-lived, one-time valid token that provides proof of authorization to the server component of the app. The authorization code is bound to the specific transaction using the state attribute passed in the authorization request. The server component of the app can validate the code using Apple’s identity service endpoint provided for this purpose. *)

*) If that value does correspond to the OIDC "code" value which will be obtained by a client via *the "front channel"* aka user agent aka browser, then we should also ensure that an additional mechanism is in place which *actually* provides a secure "proof of authorization" (Universal Links, PKCE), see [Authorization Code Interception Attack](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).
If these attacks are technically impossible, because the authentication system provides secure communication channels with the app, we don't need PKCE, though.

The id_token contains information about the user that has been authenticated which is stored on the Provider. It's a signed JWT. Even if the JWT can be successfully validated, *with the JWT alone* the app server cannot be sure that the sender is the one who it believes it is. We don't want to give anyone an access token who is not authenticated!

The app server needs more prove and this will be accomplished with the `authorizationCode` parameter. This check has to be done on the Provider though.

[So, we have to perform two steps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user):

1. [Verify the Identity Token (id_token)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user)
   This will be performed on the app server.
2. Validate Authorization Code

The second step will be accomplished by your app server [obtaining a refresh token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens) form the Providers special endpoints.

With Step 2 we receive a [TokenResponse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/tokenresponse).

If this was successful, we receive an access token and a refresh token. The access token is of no use, but we need the refresh token:

*"You may verify the refresh token up to once a day to confirm that the user’s Apple ID on that device is still in good standing with Apple’s servers."*

Store this on your app server.

Once after this is all done on your app server you proceed with:

**Manage the User Session**

*After verifying the identity token, your app is responsible for managing the user session. You may tie the session’s lifetime to successful getCredentialState(forUserID:completion:) calls on Apple devices. This is a local, inexpensive, nonnetwork call and is enabled by the Apple ID system that keeps the Apple ID state on a device in sync with Apple servers.*

A "User Session" will likely require a domain specific access token and refresh token. You will likely verify again Apple's refresh token when the client requires a new access token on your token endpoint.

So, the last step is your app sending the domain specific access token and refresh token to your client.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! This is really helpful :) I will try it with validating the authorization code as well!